# hasmany association in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, associations

I am having 2 tables users and emails with fields USERS(id,fname.lname,cardno,cardtype) && EMAILS(cardno,cardtype,payamount).

I want to access emails data on the basis of CARD NO field of users table in cakephp.
please help

Comment: My question to you is "cardno in emails table is primary key or not"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to user relationship:

in User model:

```
public $belongsTo =  array('Email' => array(
        'className' => 'Email',
        'foreignKey' => 'cardno',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

and in Email Model :

```
var $primaryKey = 'cardno';

public $hasMany = array(
    'Email' => array(
        'className' => 'Email',
        'foreignKey' => 'cardno'
         )
);
```

Comment: You have your models swapped.

Comment: above solution also helped me in completing my task

Answer (score 0):

You can set the primary key with 'cardno' and create the associations between the tables with that filed like this:
Model of user:

```
var $primaryKey = 'cardno';

 public $hasMany = array(
        'Comment' => array(
            'className'     => 'Comment',
            'foreignKey'    => 'cardno',
            'dependent'     => true
        )
    );
```

And in the model of Email:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className'    => 'User',
            'foreignKey'   => 'cardno'
        )
    );
```